# PyQt4, how to get current widget created?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a class to create a PyQt4 widget and another class to parse xml to get inputs. I want to create an UI dyanamically add buttons to the widget, reading from the xml(s) passed, which is not happening:

```
import sys

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from PyQt4 import QtGui

ui = None

class userInterface(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
    super(userInterface, self).__init__()

    def getFilesWindow(self):
        self.filesSelected = []
        fDialog = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Open file', '/Learning/Python/substance_XML_reading/', "SBS (*.sbs)")

        for path in fDialog:
            if path:self.filesSelected.append(path)
        return self.filesSelected

class ParseXML():

    def getXMLTags(self,fileList):
        self.tags = []
        if fileList:
            print fileList

        for eachFile in fileList:
            fileToParse = ET.parse(eachFile)
            root = fileToParse.getroot()
            for child in root:
                self.tags.append(child.tag)
        return self.tags

def getSetUI(flist):
    global ui
    if flist:
        tagsForBtns = ParseXML().getXMLTags(flist)
        print tagsForBtns
        for eachitem in tagsForBtns:
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton(ui,eachitem)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = userInterface()
    fileListForUIGen = ui.getFilesWindow() # will return a list of files

    getSetUI(fileListForUIGen) # Parses each file, gets tags, creates buttons and has to add to the current window..NOT WORKING

    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add buttons to a widget, you need to place them inside a `QLayout`

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.ui_lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.ui_lay)

    def addButton(self, text):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton(text, self)
        self.ui_lay.addWidget(btn)

...

for eachitem in tagsForBtns:
    ui.addButton(eachitem)
```

Also, make sure to use `global ui` in your `main()` function if you're going to be doing it this way.

Personally, I don't see the reasons for splitting up all the function calls.  I would just put them all in the `UserInterface` class.